# MST on Complete graph to cluster them (for cosine similarity)

Tags: graph, nlp, cluster-analysis, minimum-spanning-tree

I need to cluster (let's say given as parameter k), words (that I 
store in array List) according to their cosine similarity. I have stored my all words as vertexes in list in a complete ,weighed, and undirected graph (that uses adjacency list), and put their cosine similarity values on edges. As I understand I need to use MST (Kruskals Algorithm) for clustering process.

However since, my graph is complete graph and MST used for connected graphs, I am kind of confused how to use it on complete graph? Or I am doing wrong by using complete graph?

This is my wordList:

```
 [directors, producers, film, movie, black, white, man, woman, person, man, young, woman, science, fiction, thrilling, realistic, lovely, stunning, criminals, zombies, father, son, girlfriend, boyfriend, nurse, soldier, professor, college]
```

And I need to cluster them by MST so that if k (number of clusters) is 2 it will be like this (2 clusters according to their similarities):

```
boyfriend,college,father,girlfriend,man,nurse,person,professor,son,woman,young
criminals,directors,fiction,film,lovely,movie,producers,science,stunning,thrilling,zombies
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's standard to use minimum spanning trees on complete graphs.

You will often find the runtime complexity given for this case separately. You may want to check if Prim's is faster than Kruskal's on a complete graph.

Clustering with the minimum spanning tree is also known as Single-Link clustering, and the fast SLINK algorithm is closely related to Prim's MST algorithm. But the output format is more suitable for clustering.

Comment: Anony-Mouse So that means, that i can use Prim'e algorithm for finding mst on complete graph right?

Comment: If I recall correctly (you better verify) it is one of the faster standard algorithms. but it is O(n²) if I recall correctly. But for *clustering* by MST, SLINK may be better.